# cocos2D Touching screen crash

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

My application crashes when these blocks of code are executed. There are no errors, just warnings. The warning says, "Conflicting return type in implementation of 'ccTouchesBegan:withEvent':'void'VS'BOOL'(aka 'signed char')" Please help.

```
-(BOOL) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
return YES;
}

-(BOOL) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint point = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
point = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:point];

CCNode *player = [self getChildByTag:kTagPlayer];
[player setPosition:point];

CCNode *computer = [self getChildByTag:kTagComputer];
[computer runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:3.0
                                     position:ccp(player.position.x, player.position.y)]
 ];

return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your warning states these methods are required to return nothing (`void`), not a boolean value. Try to change it and see if it fixes the warning, otherwise the problem lies in your code and not in how these methods are called.

Comment: I did change it to void, the error did go away, granted my image didn't move when I put my finger on the screen. Do you see anything fishy in my coding? Thanks.

Comment: NEVER MIND!I have ccTouchesMoved. Wow I feel dumb. It all works fine. I apologize for wasting you time Jack. Thanks for helping out though. I guess it's a learning experience. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The return type on

```
-(BOOL) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

should be (void)

```
-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

there no return anything.

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

and you should use this for single touch;

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

it also support multi touch:

```
-(BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSArray *allTouches = [[event allTouches] allObjects];
    for (int i=0; i<[allTouches count];i++) {
        if ([some conditions]) {
            CGPoint position = [(UITouch*)[allTouches objectAtIndex:i] locationInView:[[CCDirector sharedDirector]openGLView]];
            position.y = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]winSize].height - position.y;
            //deal with the position;
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
return FALSE;
```

}

you must active touch interaction first:

```
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
//if support multi touch you must set swallowsTouches "NO".
```